# Sort an array of floats and apply the same sorting sequence to other arrays C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, depth

I am using the following insertion sort function to sort an array of Z-depth float values:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    float temp = depth[i];
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && depth[j] > temp; j--)
    {
        depth[j + 1] = depth[j];
    }
    depth[j + 1] = temp;
}
```

However, I have several other arrays that need to be sorted in the exact same way this one ends up being sorted. But I haven't had any success in modifying this code to apply the same sorting to all the others.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks,
-Richard

Comment: Use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), if you need reverse order use std::greater. No need to implement your own sorting algorithm for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to be sorted in the exact same way" ? That you want to use the same algorithm ? Or that if element `i` of array A end at position `j`, all elements `i` of other array must be at position `j` ?

Comment: Basically, you create an index array, rearrange the indexes using `std::sort` using the floatingpoint values, then use the indices to copy the arrays to new arrays in the rearranged order. Search for `[c++] iota index sort` and you get tons of examples how to do it.

Comment: It's recommended to use `std::sort` in the first place, but if you have to do it yourself, I think your first **for** shouldn't start at 1 and go all the way, maybe it should start from the end. And reach 0!

Comment: @Mahdy.n in insertion sort you can start with index 1 because the first element will always be inserted at first position.

Comment: @Alois It is for a particle system, for depth sorting. So if I sort the array of z depth positions from furthest to closest, I need to apply that same sorting order to all the other arrays holding color info, size info, etc. So its not about reusing the same algorithm, but using the algorithm once on the z position, and then shifting all the other arrays to follow the same indexing. I would love to use std::sort to simplify it but again, I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort these arrays with the same order, why don't you simply put all your values inside a structure, then in an array, and finally sort the array using standard algorithm (`std::sort`) with a custom comparison function?

It means that instead of having `N` arrays of `K` elements, containing each a given data type (an integer, a real, a string, whatever...), you'll have a structure with `N` fields, put in a single array of `K` elements.

If you do that at construction time, it won't cost you a lot of overhead in execution time - practically, none - and while sorting data, you'll process only one array instead of `N`, which will be faster - and even more if your final array, instead of structures, contains *pointers* to structures: it will be sorted at the same speed as your initial array of floats, but you'll sort everything instead.

If you can't modify the storage structure at all - i.e. you're stuck with `N` arrays and can't do otherwise - then rebuilding such a structure array, in a new container dedicated to this sort, may be a solution - even if it's a pure virtual one using a LUT to access the original arrays. I can go further on this point if it's what you need.

Comment: Hi Wisblade - thank you for your reply. I am not a very experienced developer regarding structures so I don't fully understand this. I will read it more carefully, do some research, and see if I can make some sense of it. I left a comment to @Alois that perhaps sheds more info about why I need to do this, and in what context. Perhaps that can help. I would love to be able to use std::sort but in my new comment I explain that I don't see how.

Comment: @Rich95 That's EXACTLY where you should use a structure, containing the particle position, AND its color, AND its size, AND its material, AND everything else. One particle, one structure, one array of particles (i.e. one array of structures). Simplest thing to do. You then use `std::sort` with a custom comparison operator. For performance reasons, cache the distance between particle and camera (=depth / Z-order) within the structure itself, so you don't have to compute it on each comparison - seems that you already have them stored, but better safe than sorry and do it.